# Эклипс: переименовать приложение

Tags: android, java

Даже не дали ответить, закрыли прошлый вопрос. Нажать Rename, ввести новое имя, нажать ОК. Это я и без вас уважаемый metalurgus догадался сделать (тут ума много не надо), да только не работает, вопрос надо внимательней читать. Мое приложение называется Application_098, переименовываю его по вашему чудо методу на Appl, при установки приложения на эмулятор как было название  Application_098 на ярлыке, так и осталось. Мне необходимо, чтоб название на ярлыке приложения поменялось, а не имя проекта.

Comment: а что вы спросили, то я вам и ответил. Вы спросили, как переименовать проект, я вам и написал, как это сделать. И кто же знает, что вы имеете в виду под "при установки его на телефон название должно быть таким как мне надо". И еще, слово "установкЕ" пишется через "е". Уж поверьте, вопрос я ваш внимательно прочитал, даже 2 раза. Это вам надо научиться правильно излагать свои мысли.

Comment: Ваш комментарий был необязателен, мне уже дали правильный ответ. А если вы не знали, что я имел ввиду, спрашивая первый раз, то и отвечать не надо было. В следующий раз буду выражаться яснее.

Comment: Я как-то сам уж без вас определю, что обязательно, а что нет. Если не желали моего комментария, нечего было меня упоминать в своем вопросе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Имя проекта никак не связано с тем, что будет отображаться в качестве названия установленного приложения. За это отвечает атрибут `android:label` тега `<application>` в `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Ну вот спасибо, за ответ, а то начали тыкать мордой в пол, не разобравшись.